# Thermostat wire does not go to Furnace

Tags: thermostat, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

My thermostat wires go to a control panel heat pump system which go to the furnance , i need to wire a c wire but not sure how to go about this with the york control panel

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the control panel and at the furnace/air handler? Does your house have multiple thermostats by chance?

Comment: It says picture is to big when I try to upload and i am new to this but basically my thermostat wire goes to my control board only not to my furnace direct

Comment: Upload the photo to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post a link to it in the comments here, then we can help you get it in from there

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rh3dJaD

Comment: attached are the pictures

Comment: Any help please

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but can you get us a photo of the *front* of the control-box that the thermostat wires attach to?

Comment: Hi sorry , i attached to this link http://imgur.com/5ynZypI
http://imgur.com/3TXr8Zt
http://imgur.com/fORDQlo

Comment: Hello i still require help if your there

Comment: Can you find a label on that box (perhaps on the inside of the cover) that provides a wiring diagram for it, and post a photo of it for me?